# swift how to add dictionary keys values in array

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I  am  working  on  swift  json Parsing  where i  am recieving  json  Data  from  Rest  API  for  eg:

```
{"baseUrl":"http:\/\/localhost:9010\/",
"pluginOptions":{"values":[{"StartSyncTime":"2020-10-06 17:22:34","uuid":"977a5d03-2cdf-4008-87e6-01594e4369ef","LastSyncTime":"2020-10-06",
"MessageWrapper":{"Routing":"OriginSession","SourceSystem":"Mobile","MessageId":"51152ccd-32c6-475b-86a6-a2c883d551f5",
"UserID":"77ee794e-433d-4b93-bcaa-53408ede50fd","TenantID":"null","TenantName":"visurtest","Payload":"{}",
"DataType":"SQLLiteDDLAsync","MessageKind":"READ"}}],
"database":"structionDB","encrypted":false,"mode":"no-encryption"}}
```

I  am  getting  as  type [String:Any?]  from  rest  api  in  below  code

```
  var pluginOptions : [String: Any]? = call.getObject("pluginOptions")
    

        pluginOptions?[MessageWrapperKeys.DataType] = [DataTypes.SQLLiteDDLAsync]

        pluginOptions?[MessageWrapperKeys.MessageKind] = [MessageKinds.READ]

        pluginOptions?[MessageWrapperKeys.Payload] = ["{}"]
```

from  above  Json  Response  i  need  to extract  MessageWrapper Dictionary like  below

```
{"Routing":"OriginSession","SourceSystem":"VisurMobile","MessageId":"51152ccd-32c6-475b-86a6-a2c883d551f5",
                  "UserID":"77ee794e-433d-4b93-bcaa-53408ede50fd","TenantID":"null","TenantName":"visurtest","Payload":"{}",
                    "DataType":"SQLLiteDDLAsync","MessageKind":"READ"}
```

where  above last  3 key  vale  i  have  added  from  code,Now  i  have  to  send  Rest  Api  Call  with   above  request  but  i  did  not  able  to   figure  it  out  how i will  extraxt  MessageWrapper  Keys  and  append  above  3 Key  Values  so  that  i  get  final  jsonString Request  like

```
{"Routing":"OriginSession","SourceSystem":"Mobile","MessageId":"05086b82-3623-492b-926a-d3bb8d01aa52","UserID":"77ee794e-433d-4b93-bcaa-53408ede50fd","TenantID":"null","TenantName":"test","Payload":"{}","DataType":"SQLLiteDDLAsync","MessageKind":"READ"}
```

below  code  i  have  triyed  but  not  able  to  access

```
func readTableFromBackend(_ call: CAPPluginCall) -> Observable<String>{
        var swrapper: [[String: Any]] = [[:]]
        var pluginOptions : [String: Any]? = call.getObject("pluginOptions")
        let  json =  JSON(pluginOptions)
        var arrayNames =  json["values"].arrayValue.map {$0["MessageWrapper"].string}
        for arrayvalues in json["values"].arrayValue{
       for arrayvalues in json["MessageWrapper"].arrayValue{
                var string =  arrayvalues["UserID"].string
              
           }
            var string =  arrayvalues["MessageWrapper"].string
          

            print(string)

        }
     pluginOptions?[MessageWrapperKeys.DataType] = [DataTypes.SQLLiteDDLAsync]

        pluginOptions?[MessageWrapperKeys.MessageKind] = [MessageKinds.READ]

        pluginOptions?[MessageWrapperKeys.Payload] = ["{}"]

        var  values = pluginOptions?["values"]

       var  modes = pluginOptions?["mode"]


        for (key,value)in  pluginOptions ?? ["":""]{
                  print("\(key) -> \(value)")
            

        }
   var finajsonstring: String = ""
  var  pluginOptions1: [String:Any] =  [MessageWrapperKeys.DataType:DataTypes.SQLLiteDDLAsync, MessageWrapperKeys.MessageKind:MessageKinds.READ,MessageWrapperKeys.Payload: "{}"]

            swrapper.append(pluginOptions ?? ["":""])

        swrapper.append(pluginOptions1 )


    let apidata = PullBackendData()

        let plugindata = PluginCallParameterOptions()

        var url: String? = call.getString("baseUrl")

       

     //   let payload = swrapper

        
        let address =  plugindata.getApiUrl(controllerName: Controllers.DataSync, baseUrl: url ?? "")
   
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: pluginOptions)

        guard let  jsonString = String(data : jsonData!, encoding: .utf8
       ) else { return  Observable.just("Error")}
  let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

        do{


            let newdata : NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary

           
           }
  if((newdata.value(forKey: "values")) != nil){

            

                let info : NSArray =  newdata.value(forKey: "values") as! NSArray

                

                let info1 : NSArray =  info.value(forKey: "MessageWrapper") as! NSArray

               

                var wrapperarray: [[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]]()

                wrapperarray = newdata.value(forKey: "values") as! [[String:Any]]

                wrapperarray.append(pluginOptions1)



                let jsonData: NSData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: info1, options: []) as NSData

                
                 let jsonData2: NSData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: wrapperarray, options: []) as NSData

     
                do {

                     var jsonstring = try  NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

                    var jsonstring2 = NSString(data: jsonData2 as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
                       //getting  final string  and  sending  to  rest  api

                    finajsonstring =  jsonstring2 as String



                }catch {

                    print("error")

                }
         

            }
       

        } catch let error as NSError{

            print(error)

        }

        let response =  apidata.post(_for: address, bodyData: finajsonstring)

        return   Observable.from(optional: response)

  }
```

Comment: You probably want to rephrase the question as its not understandable in its current form. If anyone understood, please edit or explain.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you mean, maybe you could add a simplified example of what the dictionary looks like and what you want to do.